# Are there route guards in Node JS like there are in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, single-page-application, koa

I'm learning creating `SPA` with `Angular2` & `NodeJS + Koa`. I've just studied routes guarding in `Angular2` and I wonder if there exist route guards in `NodeJS` (or `Koa`?) .

I suppose it is very important, because we can not rely on the code on the client side in security matters...

Comment: securing routes in nodejs is done with additional middleware like e.g. passport for user access and special routes which check against the securing middleware. The consepts of guards doesn't fit to routes in node.js.

Comment: @Myonara  Could you please tell me where to read about it in detail?

Comment: I've learned this from the sources of the [full mean stack package vulgar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vulgar-cli): The files are server.conf.js and config/passport.conf.js for the setup of passport as middleware and app/routes.js and e.g. app/routes/_authentication.router.js for the implementation wiithin routes.

Comment: @Myonara Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to tell nodeJS that we exited from a page, because when we exit from a route we don't send any data to nodeJS in the server side.

Comment: Oh sorry, the word "exit" was superfluous in the qestion. Sorry.